# ASP.NetCore 2.1 gives HTTP404: NOT FOUND-The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I built a test website in MVC .netcore 2.1 which is working fine in development and published on local IIS. When I run the published website it shows login page but after taking the user and password it shows blank page instead of home page. I have no idea what is the error, any help will be appreciated.

By checking F12, found following error messages:

IN **IE edge**
"HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
POST - https://localhost/ "

In **Firefox:**
"The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128)
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
             .AddDefaultUI()
             .AddDefaultTokenProviders();       

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

       AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize( x=>x.AddProfile<ProfileMappings>());
    }
}
```

AccountController.cs
This Action is being called when we submit the login form and redirect when all valid.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(AccountLoginModel model)
    {       
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            var user = Task.Run(async () => await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email)).Result;
            if (user != null && user.IsEnabled)
            {
                var result = repository.SignIn(model.Email, model.Password).Result;
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Username or/and Password is invalid.");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Username or/and Password is invalid.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the same Uri via Postman, Insomnia or some other rest client. I feel Firefox did a GET call and IE did a POST call. Also share some Controller endpoint code and also your request details.

Comment: @Ram Kumaran, I did not try via Postman, Insomnia but I am not using any API, just redirect to home controller if user details are valid otherwise stay at same page with error message.

Comment: Share the code of startup

Comment: @Ram Startup.cs added into question. Please have a look.

Comment: Share account controller code too. The default controller is configured as Account controller.

Comment: @Ram Kamaran, AccountController.cs code has been added. That code is being call when we submit the login form and redirect at home page when all valid. Thanks for your help.